# Different redirects in function of multiple referer

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect

Now I have this code of redirect in function of the referer:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log(isMobile);
  var referrer = document.referrer;
  if(referrer.indexOf('site1.com') !== -1 || referrer.indexOf('site2.com') !== -1) {

   if(isMobile.phone) {
      window.location = "http://www.landingphone.com";
      console.log('Is phone');
    } else if(isMobile.tablet) {
       window.location = "http://www.landingtablet.com";
       console.log('Is tablet');
     } else {
       window.location = "http://www.landingdesktop.com";
       console.log('Is desktop');
     }

   } else {
     window.location = "http://www.anotherlanding.com";
   }
 });
```

Its ok this code for redirect in function of the referer site1 and site2.com, but if I need redirect also another referer (for example site3.com) to another landing (for example www.landingphone2.com, landingtablet2.com and landingdesktop2.com). What I need add in the code? what i need modify?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to add some `if` or `else if` cases to your existing structure. Perhaps have a look at the [javascript tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info), it has some links to JavaScript language tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, adding another `else if` statement as referred to in the comment to your answer.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log(isMobile);
  var referrer = document.referrer;
  if (referrer.indexOf('site1.com') !== -1 || referrer.indexOf('site2.com') !== -1) {

   if (isMobile.phone) {
      window.location = "http://www.landingphone.com";
      console.log('Is phone');
    } else if (isMobile.tablet) {
       window.location = "http://www.landingtablet.com";
       console.log('Is tablet');
     } else {
       window.location = "http://www.landingdesktop.com";
       console.log('Is desktop');
     }

   } else if (referrer.indexOf('site3.com') !== -1) {

     // Do your other redirects here

   } else {
     window.location = "http://www.anotherlanding.com";
   }
 });
```

Comment: Works fine! Thank you @alexi2 !